# The cross product between two members of a vector space not a member of that space?

Tags: vector-spaces

How can I show that the cross product between two members of a vector space is not a member of that vector space?

I know that the cross product between two vectors is a pseudo-vector. How do we know that these products form a different linear space?

Comment: This is either true or false depending on the vector spaces in question.  We need more information to help you.

Comment: It's not that pseudo-vectors live in a different vector space. But rather that they carry a different representation of the automorphism group. Is that too subtle a distinction?

Comment: @Jim I don't have any specific vector space on mind. Actually I want to know why pseudo-vectors form a different linear space. I didn't know the answer depends on the vector space.

Comment: @ziggurism I got confused by "different representation of the automorphism group". I know nothing about automorpism groups. What should I study?

Comment: @Simorq representation theory is the study of how vectors transform under symmetry groups. My favorite book on the subject is Fulton and Harris, but if you've no group theory maybe you should start with a more elementary book

Comment: What do you know about cross product? How and where is it defined? And what is a pseudo-vector?

Comment: The reason why it depends on the space is take two members  of $\mathbb{R}^3$ their cross product is still in the space, meanwhile if you take a 2D subspace ( basically $\mathbb{R}^2$) and find the cross product of two elements of that one the resulting vector lies outside the space.

Comment: @edm Cross product is a form of outer product and is defined in 3D space. If you take two vectors from a vector space, their cross product is a pseudo-vector, or a bivector I guess.

Comment: @Triatticus So how do you distiguish between a cross product, and another vector from that space with the same magnitude and direction? One is a pseudo-vector and another is a vector. If they're different things, shouldn't they belong to different spaces?

Comment: Their scalar product will be zero, as the cross product will be orthogonal to all vectors in that space

Comment: Bivectors literally _do_ live in a different vector space. That is why wedge product and cross product are not the same thing, although they are related.

Answer (score 1):

I would say rather that vectors and their cross products live in the same vector space, viz. $\mathbb{R}^3$, but that vectors and pseudovectors (such as cross products) differ in the representations of the group of coordinate transformations of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

While I prefer to say that the vectors and pseudo-vectors live in the same vector space, if you wanted to insist they should live in different vector spaces, I wouldn't argue. For example, I do not think it is a good idea to add a vector and a pseudovector. Declaring them to live in distinct vector spaces rules out that possibility.

Vectors in a vector space transform under change of variables by matrix multiplication. Pseudo-vectors also transform by matrix multiplication *for matrices of positive determinant*. But they don't respond to reflection.

To see that the vector cross product is a pseudovector and not a vector, just observe

$$(-u)\times(-v)=u\times v.$$

So reflecting vectors $u$ and $v$ through the origin does not yield a reflection through the origin of $u\times v.$

In representation theoretic terms, vectors carry a faithful representation of of $\text{Aut}(V)$ aka $GL(V)$, but pseudovectors carry a representation that is trivial on $GL(V)/GL_+(V),$ where $GL_+(V)$ is the subgroup of transformations of positive determinant.

Comment: Would this answer even be useful and helpful to the asker?

Comment: @edm I have edited it to make it more elementary. Is it better?

Answer (score 1):

The key fact is that the cross product of two vectors is orthogonal to both of those vectors.  Suppose you have two vectors v and w.  Then those two vectors define a plane, which is span(v,w).  This plane is a vector space; let's cal it P, and a basis of P is {v,w}.  Let x=cross(v,w).  Then x is in P_orthogonal, and therefore not in P.

Comment: So how do you distiguish between a cross product, and another vector from that space with the same magnitude and direction? One is a pseudo-vector and another is a vector. If they're different things, shouldn't they belong to different spaces?